# Error on compilation of x264 on qnap

Tags: compilation, installation, libx264, qnap

We are facing issues on compiling x264 on qnap.
We need to compile ffmpeg with x264 library, qnap packages have the built-in x264 0.66 library but ffmpeg-0.9.2 doesn't support too old version of x264 and produces the following error on compiling x264 from source.

```
[/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/x264-snapshot-20130208-2245] # make
gcc -Wshadow -O3 -ffast-math -m32  -Wall -I. -I. -march=i686 -mfpmath=sse -msse -std=gnu99  -I/opt/include    -I/opt/include   -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-tree-vectorize   -c -o x264.o x264.c
x264.c: In function 'help':
x264.c:401: error: 'X264_VERSION' undeclared (first use in this function)
x264.c:401: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
x264.c:401: error: for each function it appears in.)
make: *** [x264.o] Error 1


[/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/x264-snapshot-20130208-2245] # cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.33.2 (root@NasX86-4) (gcc version 4.1.3 20070929 (prerelease) (Ubuntu 4.1.2-16ubuntu2)) #1 SMP Wed Dec 5 06:48:23 CST 2012
```

Can someone assist me on that ?

Answer (score 2):

Probably `version.sh` does not have execution permission. So, `chmod 744 version.sh` then retry configure and make.

Answer (score 1):

X264_VERSION define is generated in x264_config.h during configure script execution by calling to version.sh. So either it wasn't generated in x264_config.h (some fault of your building environment and need analyze of config.log) or you have old x264.h headers somewhere in you include path which for some reason used instead of new one.

Answer (score 1):

Removing `--prefix="path"` from the `./configure` arguments fixed this error for me.